# Will I weigh more if I have fever?

Tags: mass, temperature, mass-energy

$E=mc^2$ means that energy is mass, and adding energy to an object (that is, making it hotter) makes it more massive.

So if my body temperature increases, will I weigh more?
or will i become lighter because with heat, I will expand and my density will reduce?

Comment: How you **feel** with a fever is not related to physical mass changes  in your body,

Comment: Increasing the temperature of a body indeed slightly increases its mass, but since the source of that heat energy was already in you (its chemical energy was just transformed), the answer is no. Moreover, it's more likely that more energy will be radiated away (so, less mass in you) due to the increased temperature.

Comment: How in the world did you think this deserves a "relativity" tag?  Removed.

Comment: If you are really interested in how your body tries to keep itself at a "normal" temperature, you might read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis

Comment: Why did someone vote to close as *primarily opinion based*? On what basis?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes - the questions is clear and isn't opinion based. @Carl This question does concern relativity and - though I think mass-energy is a more appropriate tag - it wasn't foolish or pretentious of the OP to use that tag.

Comment: @innisfree Well, no it really doesn't.  emc2 is not relativity, even if it's a subsidiary result. So unless you're going to go over to "hotter-->faster motion--> relativistic mass, I'll stand pat.

Comment: @KyleKanos I voted to close on opinion basis Kyle, because the feeling of heat in a fever is subjective, so to me its literally an opinion based question, I may be wrong but that was my reasoning,I don't mean to be pedantic, though

Comment: @count_to_10: If OP were actually concerned with the sensation of warmth during a fever, I might agree with you. However, OP is concerned with the *objective increase in temperature* & its (possible) correspondence with an increase in mass. I don't see how that is an opinion.

Comment: @KyleKanos your point is taken and  I will reverse my close vote, if I can

Answer (score 4):

The heat you dissipate during a fever comes from chemical bonds inside your body. So you are actually loosing energy to the environment faster than you would if healthy, making you (in principle) weigh less.

However, I'd like to stress that **this effect is terribly small** compared to everything else that's going on in a system as complex as the human body. That $c^2$ in Einstein's equation is a huge number, so the tiny amount of chemical energy corresponds to a tiny amount of mass. All the exchanges of chemicals with the environment that are going on in your body (sweating, metabolism, respiration, ...) are much more relevant to your body's total mass.